# Well defined mappings in the rationals

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am trying to show that $\alpha:\mathbb{Q}^+\rightarrow\mathbb{Q}$ is well defined, when $\alpha\left(\frac{n}{m}\right)=\left(\frac{n-m}{n+m}\right)$.

What I know is I need to show $\left[\frac{n}{m} \right]=\left[\frac{n_1}{m_1} \right]$ implies $\left(\frac{n-m}{n+m}\right)=\left(\frac{n_1-m_1}{n_1+m_1}\right)$.

I also know that $\left[\frac{n}{m} \right]=\left[\frac{n_1}{m_1} \right]$ is $\frac{n}{m}\equiv\frac{n_1}{m_1}$.

My question is, can I manipulate this $\frac{n}{m}\equiv\frac{n_1}{m_1}$ into $\left(\frac{n-m}{n+m}\right)=\left(\frac{n_1-m_1}{n_1+m_1}\right)$? Or am I on the wrong track in showing $\alpha$ is well defined?

Comment: There's actually a simple way to prove this. Try dividing the top and the bottom by something.

Comment: If you can write $\alpha(x)$ directly as a formula involving $x$, it'll even clearer that it's well-defined. Matt's hint is in that direction. But anyway, rewrite $\frac{n}{m}=\frac{n'}{m'}$ and $\frac{n-m}{n+m}=\frac{n'-m'}{n'+m'}$ by clearing denominators and see if you can go from the first to the second.

Comment: Thank you both very much! I was concerned that I couldn't replace $\equiv$ with $=$ in $\frac{n}{m}\equiv\frac{n_1}{m_1}$.